# Member variables seem to change by their own.?

Tags: c++, object, variables, scope, arduino

Usually given answers on Stack Overflow are enough to deal with problems which I come across, but now I'm running into sth. special...

I'm trying to build a custom and modular solution for driving a stepper motor using a shift register. For this I tried to implement a "RegisterWrite" function (just like Arduinos "digitalWrite") to change the states of the registers output pins.

Now it seems that I cannot use values of the member variables of my "register" object in its member functions. I don't know where I screwed up...

I'm trying to compress my codes as much as possible:

main.cpp

```cpp
#include<Register.h>
Register register1(8, 16, 2, 0);

void motor(){                            //this function is called via a html request handle

  uint8_t value[8] = {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0};    //setting values for register outputs
  register1.setOutputValues(value);        //writing values to member variable
  register1.setOutput();                   //actually setting the output of the register
}

void setup(){
  something something
}

void main(){
  something something
}
```

Register.h

```cpp
#ifndef REGISTER_H
#define REGISTER_H
#include<Arduino.h>

class Register{

private:
  int _NumberOutputs;                                     

public:
  uint8_t _OutputValues[];                                    
  uint8_t _DataPin;                                           
  uint8_t _ClockPin;                                          
  uint8_t _ShiftPin;   

  Register(int NOutputs, uint8_t Data, uint8_t Clock, uint8_t Shift);
  Register();

  void setOutputValues(uint8_t OValues[]);
  void setOutput();
};

#endif
```

Register.cpp

```cpp
#include<Register.h>
#include<Arduino.h>

Register::Register(int NOutputs, uint8_t Data, uint8_t Clock, uint8_t Shift){
  _NumberOutputs = NOutputs;
  _DataPin = Data;
  _ClockPin = Clock;
  _ShiftPin = Shift;
}

Register::Register(){
}

void Register::setOutputValues(uint8_t OValues[]){
  for (int i = 0; i < _NumberOutputs; i++){
    _OutputValues[i] = OValues[i];
  }
}

void Register::setOutput(){

  digitalWrite(_DataPin, 0);
  ....
  ....
}
```

This is, where the value of _DataPin ends up being "1" instead of "16" what screws up the code.

Now in addition, if I go back to `main.cpp`... Before I call `register1.setOutput()` the actual value of `_DataPin` is "16", and then again after calling `register1.setOutput()`. It seems that only inside of `register1.setOutput()` `_DataPin` equals 1. I Have no clue.

Comment: The size of `_OutputValues[]` array is unknow, you never give it a size. So `_OutputValues[i]=...` is UB, likely changing other var memory values. Better use a std::vector.

Comment: @Ripi2 There is no `std::vector` on Arduino.

Comment: @Ripi2 Giving the array a size is what did the trick for me... No chance that i would have found this on my own! Many thanks!